# Calculate the rate of change of a number over time

Tags: shell-script

I have a program that processes files. I can use ls | wc to see the count of files drop like so:

```
ubuntu@h:/home/user/data/013176$ ls -1 | wc
3245666 29210987 246670579
ubuntu@h:/home/user/data/013176$ ls -1 | wc
2768811 24919292 210429599
ubuntu@h:/home/user/data/013176$ ls -1 | wc
2662466 23962187 202347379
```

I was wondering if there is a tool to calculate the rate that the files are being consumed to see something like this over time:

`Current File Count: 2662466 rate = 5.6/s`

even better if it could estimate the time to completion based on the current count and the rate

Comment: Updated script to show completion time and also added idea of having live updates of progress and time with while loop.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple proof of concept would this meet your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash

initial_state=$(ls -1 | wc -l)
sleep 1
current_state=$(ls -1 | wc -l)
rate=$(echo $initial_state - $current_state | bc)
eta=$(echo $current_state / $rate | bc)

echo "Current file count: $current_state rate = $rate /s"
echo "Aprox. time to completion: $eta"
```

This will read the initial state of the directory it's run in then recheck 1 second (aprox.) later then give you a rate of change per second output.  From there it would be simple to calculate the aprox. time to completion.

EDIT: Added very very simple and rough completion time.

EDIT: To get live updates you could add a simple while loop to the script but doing so will lock that terminal while its running.